# How to find the indices where there are n consecutive zeroes in a row

Tags: r, vector, sequence, difference

Suppose I have this data:

```
  x = c(14,14, 6,  7 ,14 , 0 ,0  ,0 , 0,  0,  0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  9  ,1 , 3  ,8  ,9 ,15,  9 , 8, 13,  8,  4 , 6 , 7 ,10 ,13,  3,
 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0,  0,  0,  0,  0  ,0,  0 , 0 , 0,  0,  0,  0,  0 , 0,  0, 4 , 7  ,4,  5 ,16 , 5  ,5 , 9 , 4  ,4,  9 , 8,  2,  0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0,  0,  0,  0  ,0 , 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,0)

x
 [1] 14 14  6  7 14  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  1  3  8  9 15  9  8
[26] 13  8  4  6  7 10 13  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[51]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  7  4  5 16  5  5  9  4  4  9  8  2  0  0  0  0
[76]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I want to recover the indices beginning where there are more than 3 zeroes in a row and terminating with the last 0 before a nonzero.

For example,

I would get

6, 17 for the first rash of zeroes, etc.

Comment: By definition there will always be a "last zero before a nonzero". What is that conditions supposed to really be?

Comment: The last zero in the sequence of zeroes before it switches back to nonzero numbers again

Comment: You then want two sequences of numbers a) the starting locations of three zeros or greater and b) the ending locations of those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are two base R approaches:

**1) rle** First run `rle` and then compute `ok` to pick out the sequences of zeros that are more than 3 long.  We then compute the `starts` and `ends` of all repeated sequences subsetting to the `ok` ones at the end.

```
with(rle(x), {
  ok <- values == 0 & lengths > 3
  ends <- cumsum(lengths)
  starts <- ends - lengths + 1
  data.frame(starts, ends)[ok, ]
})
```

giving:

```
  starts ends
1      6   17
2     34   58
3     72   89
```

**2) gregexpr**   Take the sign of each number -- that will be 0 or 1 and then concatenate those into a long string.  Then use `gregexpr` to find the location of at least 4 zeros.  The result gives the starts and the ends can be computed from that plus the `match.length` attribute minus 1.

```
s <- paste(sign(x), collapse = "")
g <- gregexpr("0{4,}", s)[[1]]
data.frame(starts = 0, ends = attr(g, "match.length") - 1) + g
```

giving:

```
  starts ends
1      6   17
2     34   58
3     72   89
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Starts = which(diff(x == 0) == 1) + 1
Ends   = which(diff(x == 0) == -1)
if(length(Ends) < length(Starts)) {
    Ends = c(Ends, length(x)) }

Starts
[1]  6 34 72
Ends
[1] 17 58 89
```

This works for your test data, but allows *any* sequence of zeros, including short ones. To insure that you get sequences of length at least n, add:

```
n=3
Long = which((Ends - Starts) >= n)
Starts = Starts[Long]
Ends = Ends[Long]
```

Answer (score 7):

By using `dplyr` , get the `diff` then if the diff not equal to 0 , they are not belong to same group , after `cumsum` we get the grouid

```
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame('x'=x,rownumber=seq(length(x)))
df$Groupid=cumsum(c(0,diff(df$x==0))!=0)
df%>%group_by(Groupid)%>%summarize(start=first(rownumber),end=last(rownumber),number=first(x),size=n())%>%filter(number==0&size>=3)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Groupid start   end number  size
    <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int>
1       1     6    17      0    12
2       3    34    58      0    25
3       5    72    89      0    18
```

Answer (score 6):

If `x` happens to be a column of a `data.table` you can do

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = x)

dt[, if(.N > 3 & all(x == 0)) .(starts = first(.I), ends = last(.I))
   , by = rleid(x)]

#    rleid starts ends
# 1:     5      6   17
# 2:    22     34   58
# 3:    34     72   89
```

Explanation:

- `rleid(x)` gives an ID (integer) for each element in `x` indicating
  which "run" the element is a member of, where "run" means a sequence
  of adjacent equal values.
- `dt[, <code>, by = rle(x)]` partitions `dt` according to `rleid(x)` and computes `<code>` for each subset of `dt`'s rows. The results are stacked together in a single `data.table`.
- `.N` is the number of elements in the given subset
- `.I` is the vector of row numbers corresponding to the subset
- `first` and `last` give the first and last element of a vector
- `.(<stuff>)` is the same as `list(<stuff>)`

  The `rleid` function, `by` grouping within the brackets, .N and .I symbols, `first` and `last` functions are part of the `data.table` package.