# How can I split non consecutive numbers in different lists

Tags: r, vector

I have the following list of numeric values in R:

```
sales_by_hour = c(130, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 244, 391, 408, 431, 0, 0, 471, 
                  530, 573, 643, 643, 667, 787, 990, 1024, 1012, 712)
```

Then I have applied the following code to obtain the indexes of the min values

```
which(test2==0)
```

which returns the values `c(3,4,5,6,12,13)`. However I would like to then split again this list in 2 or more lists ex. `c(3,4,5,6)` and `c(12,13)`, since I want to separate non consecutive series of number.

Comment: ```split(which(sales_by_hour==0), cumsum(c(1, diff(which(sales_by_hour==0)) != 1)))```

Comment: Related: [How to find the indices where there are n consecutive zeroes in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311720/how-to-find-the-indices-where-there-are-n-consecutive-zeroes-in-a-row/)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in `base`:

```r
split(which(sales_by_hour==0), cumsum(c(1, diff(which(sales_by_hour==0)) != 1)))

#> $`1`
#> [1] 3 4 5 6
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 12 13
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) rleid** Using the input in the Note at the end, we can use `rleid` from data.table. It assigns a unique number to each run in the input resulting in a compact solution.

```
library(data.table)
split(seq_along(x)[x == 0], rleid(x)[x == 0])
```

giving:

```
$`3`
[1] 3 4 5 6

$`9`
[1] 12 13
```

**2) Base R** This could also be done in base at the expense of a slightly longer solution. Here the value of `inverse.rle(r)` is the same as the value of  `rleid(x)` and is done without using any packages.

```
r <- rle(x)
r$values <- seq_along(r$values)
split(seq_along(x)[x == 0], inverse.rle(r)[x == 0])
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Line <- "130   21    0    0    0    0    6  244  391  408  431  0  0  471  530  573  643  643  667  787  990 1024 1012  712"
x <- scan(text = Line)
```